# LDO PSRR Value Problem

Tags: power, noise, ldo

I am searching a LDO for my design but I have a problem. Some of the LDOs don't have PSRR value. So, I can not compare these LDOs then others for noise feature. For example here are 2 LDO.

Why these LDOs don't have PSRR value? What does it mean?

MCP1801T-3302I/OT

[image]

AP7354-33W5-7
(doesn't have PSRR Value)

Comment: For example I want to compare for noise rejection MCP1801T-3302I/OT and AP7354-33W5-7. But the second one doesn't have PSRR value.

Comment: Oh, you already put the part numbers. Didn't see, sorry. Deleting my previous comment.

Comment: hah no problem, I know this is about my low experience but I can't find answer on the google :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both datasheets actually do have data on the power supply ripple rejection.

The datasheet for the [AP7354-33W5-7](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP7354.pdf) doesn't list a single number in the specifications table, but it has this:

[image]

Likewise, the [MCP1801T-3302I/OT](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22051d.pdf) has this:

[image]

You can get a more detailed comparison using the charts than you would get from a single line in a table.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I think that AP7354 series look not good at PSRR so they dont give specifications table on it.